# How can I useDebounce to debounce a handle submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, debouncing

I am trying to create a button undo when the User hits the invite button to invite another user into the team and it the invitation will take 10s and then send the invite to that user meanwhile make the undo button appear and in 10s user can undo the invitation.

How can I use useDebounce in this case?

Here is my following code:

```
import { useDebounce } from "use-debounce";

const InviteCard = (props) => {
  const {
    user,
    tab,
    teamId,
    privateTeamId,
    onSubmiteInvitee,
    isInvitationAvailable,
    searchQuery,
    invite,
  } = props;

  async function inviteToTeam(e) {
    if (!user.verifiedDT) {
      notify("User has not verified their identity, can not invite.");
    } else {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/invites/invite", {
        userToInvite: user.public_user_id,
        teamId: teamId,
      });
      if (res.data.inviteWasCreated === false) {
        notify("User has already been invited.");
      } else if (res.data.error !== undefined) {
        notify(res.data.error);
      } else if (res.data.msg) {
        if (res.data.msg === "max members") {
          toggleRequestModal();
          setLimitType("team members");
        }
        if (res.data.msg === "max invites") {
          toggleRequestModal();
          setLimitType("invites");
        }
      } else {
        notify("Invite sent.");
        setWhatToReload("invite data");
        onSubmiteInvitee(e);
      }
    }
  }

  const handleSubmitInvite = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inviteToTeam(e);
  };

  let debounceInvite = useDebounce(inviteToTeam, 500);

  useEffect(() => {

  }, [debounceInvite]);

  return (
    <div ref={domNode}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmitInvite}>
              <button type="submit" className="invitees-invite-button">
                Invite
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
  );
};

export default InviteCard;
```

Update. add new function:

```
  const [sent, setSent] = useState(false);
  const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState();
  const handleSubmitInvite = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // call "inviteToTeam" function after 10s
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      inviteToTeam(e);
    }, 10 * 1000);

    setSent(!sent);
    // save the timer id in the state
    setTimeoutId(id);
  };

  const onUndoClick = (timeoutId) => {
    // get the timeout id from the state
    // and cancel the timeout
    setSent(false);
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  };

        {!sent &&
          !isInvitationAvailable(privateTeamId, user.InvitesApplications) && (
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmitInvite}>
                <button type="submit" className="invitees-invite-button">
                  Invite
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          )}
        {sent && <button onClick={onUndoClick}>Undo</button>}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need debounce in this case.

You can use `setTimeout` with 10 seconds delay to delay the invocation of the `inviteToTeam` function and if the user clicks the "undo" button before `inviteToTeam` function is invoked, you can cancel the timeout using the `clearTimeout()` function.

```
const handleSubmitInvite = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   
   // call "inviteToTeam" function after 10s
   const id = setTimeout(() => {
     inviteToTeam(e);
   }, 10 * 1000);

   // save the timer id in the state
   setTimeoutId(id);
};
```

If the "undo" button is clicked, cancel the timeout

```
const onUndoClick = () => {
   // get the timeout id from the state
   // and cancel the timeout
   clearTimeout(timeoutId);
};
```

To save the timeout id, you need to create the state for it.

```
const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState(null);
```

Comment: I have to create [timeOutId, setTimeOutId] right?

Comment: I just added my new code below my question. Can you look over it for me? Thanks alot

Comment: It works. thank you so much! You know who can I show the timeout count down in und button?

Comment: You need `setInterval` for that and `counter` state that starts the counter at 10 and `setInterval` decrements the counter state every second.

Comment: Like create a new state for that and add into `handlesubmitInvitee`?

Comment: Yes, you need to call `setInterval` as soon as the `setTimeout` is called.